# What is the high performance integration between Android App and remote or on the cloud Database?

Tags: android

I am developing Android application which needs to make frequent updates to remote or cloud based MySQL database when it is being used by the user such as user adding a new friend, this information are persisted on a remote database.

What is the high performance method of integrating Android app to remote database?

Assume the application that manages the remote databased is Java based.

Possibilities include:

Use plain HTTP URLs just like in a standard web application

Use JMS

Use Web Services

Use ESB based solution

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately you will have one of three possible solutions, either a SOAP service, a url/REST service or open your own socket.

SOAP is generally not a good solution for mobile devices, there is a lot of overhead and is not supported right out of the box, on the Android.

So, you come down to posting to a URL, which is similar to a REST service.  This is the lightest method, but then you need to decide how to package it, as, the more data you have to send the lower the performance.

So, you can go with your own encoding scheme, use xml or JSON, for example.  Using your own scheme is basically reinventing the wheel, IMO, and I prefer JSON as you can choose not to include labels, so you just send the data, with a few extra characters that are needed.

You could open your own socket connection, but then, that is reinventing the wheel also.

So, for the best performance, I would go with a REST service, and basically just submit JSON data as this will require the best performance for the least amount of work.

I forgot, your performance will take a hit based on what the server-side does. For example, if you use an ESB-based solution, that is still calling a SOAP webservice (bad idea) but then you have the performance hit from the data flow there.

JMS/ESB really depends on what you require for other operational needs. For example, if I send data to your server and then your server goes down before it processes, should I just send the data again, or will it need to be able to continue from where it stopped.

This depends on what you are processing. If you processed a credit card, then resending is a bad idea, as that means that the card gets charged twice, but adding a friend should be fine, as you can determine the friend was already added and do an update.